# QUnit, assert not OK?

Tags: qunit

Sorry if this is obvious, but is there a notOK or equivalent function in QUnit, if we want to assert that a method returns false?

I can't see a way to negate OK in the [documentation](http://api.qunitjs.com/).

I tried:

```
!ok...
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use: `ok(!method_expected_to_be_false)`

Comment: I just found this answer while searching for an alternative to the now-existing `notOk` assertion.  I was hoping to find a simple `assert.false()` because expecting something to be "false" is very different than expecting something to be "not ok" (which suggests failure - an exception, rejected promise, etc)

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation :

> The most basic assertion in QUnit, ok() requires just one argument. If
>   the argument evaluates to true, the assertion passes; otherwise, it
>   fails.

You can verify that a method return a false value by writing an expression which evaluates to a `true` value in the case the method returns `false`, and vice versa. The easiest expression to do this is the NOT operator, which in JavaScript is expressed through `!`

```
test( "Test method returns false ", function() {
  ok( method() == false, "Method returned false" );
  // or using a the negation operator
  ok( !method(), "Method returned false" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The better approach would be to use:

```
notOk(<something>);
```

as it will be more expressive than stating:

```
ok(!<something>);
```

Comment: Not sure how long ago you checked the QUnit documentation, but there is a notOk (https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/notOk/) so I suggest to use that.

Answer (score 1):

starting from [qunit 1.18](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/1.20.0/History.md) there is a dedicated function:

```
assert.notOk(valueToBeTested);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you really, really want, you can add it with `QUnit.extend()`:

```
QUnit.extend(QUnit.assert, {
    notOk: function (result, message) {
        message = message || (!result ? "okay" : "failed, expected argument to be falsey, was: " +
        QUnit.dump.parse(result));
        QUnit.push(!result, result, false, message);
    },
});
```