# When to use the .not function in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jasmine

When should you use the `.not` function in Jasmine, because it appears to be very limited.

I'm testing a function at the moment where a url (string) gets made out of 3 input fields that contain address data.

The postal code gets stripped of spaces, so I wrote a test that checks it does `.not` contain a space.. but when something else in that function goes wrong, the test will still pass because it is *not* the string I was expecting..

Makes sense. **So when should/can you use the .not function?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [QUnit, assert not OK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994755/qunit-assert-not-ok)

Comment: Nope. I'm wondering when to use the .not function. I already know how to do it. (That's why I asked the question)

Comment: The [question itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994755/qunit-assert-not-ok) is your answer: `if we want to assert that a method returns false?`

Comment: But then you could just use .toBeFalse. Surely there must be a better goal for '.not'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, the [Jasmine docs](https://github.com/btakita/jasmine#writing-new-matchers) describe it as such:

> Every matcher's criteria can be inverted by prepending .not

In general, negation methods are used as a basic form of mocking.

**References**

- [Universal unit testing (browser, Node.js) with Jasmine](http://2ality.com/2011/10/jasmine.html)
- [AngularJS Jasmine Matchers](https://github.com/ferronrsmith/angularjs-jasmine-matchers)